# how can I push in this array?

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I'm trying to push another fruit in the array with push. But it doesn't work, when I run this I'm getting the same array.
can you help me please.

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="fruit in fruits">
      {{fruit.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        fruits:[
            {name:'apple'},
            {name:'banana'},
            {name:'orange'}
        ]
    }
})

vue.fruits.push({name:'pear'});
```

Comment: maybe this.Vue.fruits.push({name:'pear'}); Due to mispelling vue->Vue

Answer (score 0):

i get the answer is only do this:

```
var vueApp=new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        fruits:[
            {name:'apple'},
            {name:'banana'},
            {name:'orange'}
        ]
    }
})

vueApp.$data.fruits.push({name:'pear'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reference to the Vue instance, then you can access the `fruits` data property directly on the instance:

```js
const comp = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        fruits: [
            { name: 'apple' },
            { name: 'banana' },
            { name: 'orange' }
        ]
    }
})

comp.fruits.push({ name: 'pear' })
```